# keras shape of variable sized training data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I got the following model implemented with Keras (tensorflow):

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, None, None, 32)    896
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, None, None, 32)    9248
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, None, None, 32)    0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, None, None, 32)    0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, None, None, 64)    18496
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, None, None, 64)    36928
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, None, None, 64)    0
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_1 ( (None, 64)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               16640
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 14)                3598
=================================================================
Total params: 85,806
Trainable params: 85,806
Non-trainable params: 0
```

My Dataset is the Leed Sports Set with images of variable width and height. According to Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d) and following github [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1920) I just have to set the inputshape to `(None, None, Num_Channels)`. To prepare my dataset I load the annotation and images as numpy arrays like this:

```
# Train Input, contains paths of images first
x_train = image_list[train_indexes]

print("Converting x_train images to numpy...")
x_train = np.array([misc.imread(path) for path in x_train])
print(x_train.shape)
print(x_train[0].shape)
print(x_train[1].shape)
```

The output of the print calls are:

```
(9600,) # x_train
(188, 282, 3) # x_train first image
(686, 1024, 3) # x_train second image
```

if I feed now `x_train` to my model it throw s the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (9600, 1)
```

How can I shape my training set to get accepted by my model?

Answer (score 0):

Keras expects you to input a single tensor for `x_train` which matches the shape of your input (a 4-dimensional tensor). What you have created in `x_train` is a 1-D array of 3-D array objects of varying shapes, not a 4-D array. This is not a tensor. A tensor can not be jagged, it can not have rows of varying shapes.

Keras requires you to input tensors because of vectorization. In order to get the benefits of vectorization, all inputs must be tensors. Keras can not handle jagged tensors, nor can numpy. To run inputs of varying shapes, what you will have to do to utilize the vectorization of Keras would be to pad every image (with 0's in all 3 channels) so that they are uniform in shape. Alternatively, you can write a for-loop where you run your inputs through your model one at a time. This would essentially lose all the benefits of vectorization and it might take an extremely long time to train your model.

Comment: Can you maybe give a example for your padding option?

Comment: You can maybe look into np.pad: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html

Comment: as far as I see `np.pad` has to get a fixed amount to pad with. How can I  do that with my variable size problematic?

Comment: You can set one default size and then write a function to figure out how much you have to pad a certain image based on the size of the image compared to the default size (basic subtraction stuff), and then pad the image using np.pad.

Comment: Also have a look at spatial pyramid pooling as a way to build CNNs that take any size input image: https://github.com/yhenon/keras-spp